# ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 - wildcard mapping - the incoming request does not match any route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, iis-6

I have been trying to set up my Beta 1 MVC app on IIS 6 and cannot get it to run correctly. I have added a Wildcard mapping to the .net isapi DLL as suggested in other blog posts but get the following error when I access the root of the website:

```
The incoming request does not match any route.
..
[HttpException (0x80004005): The incoming request does not match any route.]
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +147
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +36
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +4
   HCD.Intranet.Web.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +81
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +15
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +33
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +47
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1436
```

I am using the Default.aspx page supplied in the MVC template application that rewrites access to the root of the website properly.

```
public partial class Default : Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

If I try and access a route within the application, such as /Project, I get the standard IIS 404 error page, not the .net error page.

I tried adding the following line to my Web.config httpHandlers section:

```
<add verb="*" path="*" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

This gave me a different error - the .net 404 error page.

I added the following to my Global.asax, which did nothing:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Request.FilePath.Equals("/"))
        Context.RewritePath("Default.aspx");
}
```

I am using the following route configuration (uses the restful routing supplied by the MvcContrib project):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
SimplyRestfulRouteHandler.BuildRoutes(routes);
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", 
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Any suggestions would be grealy received as I've exhausted all options for the time I have right now.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, got it working.

The problem was that I was using msbuild automation to package up the files that I needed to deploy, and I was missing global.asax.

So it looks like if global.asax is not deployed to the site then none of the routes get hooked up. This means that hitting the website root correctly results in the error 'The incoming request does not match any route.', and any other requests no longer get routed through to your controller classes, so result in a 404.

HTH.

Comment: Perfect - this was my problem. I was building via NAnt/MSBuild and was not including the Global.asax file. Having that file there solves everything.

Comment: Hmm, I have the same problem, and I too am using build scripts to package up the files, but my Global.asax file is definitely present in the web root folder.

Answer (score 18):

Here's what I did to get extensionless URLs working with IIS 6 and ASP.NET MVC Beta 1.

- Create a default ASP.NET MVC Beta
  project and compile it.
- Create a new IIS website pointing to
  the application directory.
- In the IIS properties for the
  website, click the HomeDirectory
  tab.
- Click the "Configuration..." button.
  In the "Mappings" tab, click
  "Insert..."
- Next to the "Wildcard application
  maps" label In the textbox, type in
  "c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"
- Uncheck the box labelled "Verify
  that file exists" Click OK
- Navigate to /home It worked!

You shouldn't need to change web.config at all. You just need to map all requests to IIS to the ASP.NET Isapi dll otherwise ASP.NET will never get those requests.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, especially the 'Uncheck the box labelled "Verify that file exists" Click OK' step that I had forgotten about.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly IIS 6 needs a file extension to map the request to the right handler which means you will have to use the .mvc suffix on your controller names, such as  */{controller}.mvc/{action}*

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

SimplyRestfulRouteHandler.BuildRoutes(routes);

routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

However, the are ways around this depending on your level of control on the IIS 6 server. Please refer to the following pages for more information

- http://biasecurities.com/blog/2008/how-to-enable-pretty-urls-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis6/
- http://www.flux88.com/UsingASPNETMVCOnIIS6WithoutTheMVCExtension.aspx