# error 500 using webservices on IIS 6.0 WS 2003

Tags: c#, web-services

I have developped a web service using c# and Asp.net and this works fine on my local machine where I use vista and IIS7.0. I call it via Jquery using this url

http://localhost/myWebservice/vote

But when I try it on the preproduction site, I receive an 500 error from the server telling me the /vote is not good. I still can access it directly in the browser when typing ?op=vote, but I have then an error saying the formatting of my xml is not right.

Am I missing something in the configuration of the IIS 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

To use routes in IIS 6 you probably need a wildcard mapping in IIS; along the same lines [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275920#279386) (for ASP.NET MVC, but the same concept) - although to be honest, I'd expect a 4xx for a file not found.

500 typically indicates a more serious problem - for example, the app-pool identity isn't configured correctly and can't execute as a service. Check the event log on the server for messages.

---

As an aside; always try to develop on something as close to the actual hosting platform as you can. For example, I run a Win2003 server in a VM for hosting IIS6. This saves a lot of unexpected surprises when you come to deploy.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I will have a check on this.
-------------------------------------------
And I totally agree with you, but I did not choose anything, it was like this whan I came in this job...  :S