# MVC 3 Deployment to IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Originally, I deployed the site with some of the DLL's set to copy local (as haacked suggested on another SO post).  After this failed, I installed MVC 3 package on the server.

When I hit my site I get:

> Directory Listing Denied This Virtual
>   Directory does not allow contents to
>   be listed.

I saw [haacked's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx), but its almost 3 years old now and some of it just doesn't work anymore.  Does anyone know what we need to do to get this to work after we installed MVC 3 on the server?

**UPDATE**
I found another [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) on haacked's blog.  Apparently, this should just work (no need to do wildcard mappings).  My website virtual directory is set to run ASP.NET 4.0.30319, I have installed ASP.NET MVC 3, and I am running IIS6 (windows server 2003 R2, Pretty sure that is IIS6).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Virtual Directory was set to ASP.NET 4.0.  While, the "Default Web Site" was set to run ASP.NET 2.0.  I changed the "Default Web Site" to run 4.0 in addition to the virt. directory and it started working.  The reason is a mystery to me, but it worked.

Comment: Note that changing the default web site to 4.0 wreaked havoc on many of my existing virtual directories (still set to run 2.0).  I had to create a seperate website to house my 4.0 based virt. dir's.

Comment: Creating a separate web site for .NET 4.0 applications worked for me too.

Comment: Virtual Directory ≠ Web Application. Virtual directory: when the physical location varies from the IIS location, relative to the wwwroot. Web Application: The thing that's created when you click "Create" in IIS admin. #PetPeeve #Pedantry

Comment: +1 @brianary you are correct. still there is a big difference between the word 'virtual directory' in terms of IIS 6.0 and and IIS 7.x. For IIS 6.0 a virtual directory itself acts as an application too.

Comment: In IIS 6.0, a virtual directory is only an application if you enable script or executable processing in the wizard, or click the Create button in the properties. They are independent. #Pedantry

Answer (score 22):

It sounds like you haven't set up the wildcard mapping.  You need to configure a mapping in IIS that sends all requests to ASP.NET pipeline for processing.  Since you don't have the mapping set up, it interprets the request as a directory browse (which is probably disallowed in your configuration).

[From Haacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275920/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-wildcard-mapping-the-incoming-request-does-not-match-any/279386#279386):

1. In the IIS properties for the website, click the Home Directory tab.
2. Click the "Configuration..." button. In the "Mappings" tab, click "Insert..."
3. Next to the "Wildcard application maps" label In the textbox, type in "c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"
4. Uncheck the box labeled "Verify that file exists" Click OK

Comment: Windows Server 2003 R2 is indeed IIS6.  Without seeing the link you mentioned, I think Haacked must have been referring to IIS 7 that it "should just work".  AFAIK, IIS6 always needs the wildcard mapping whether its MVC3/.NET 4.0 or not.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I didn't know that ASP.NET 4 took care of that issue.

Comment: Step 3: isn't it C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

Comment: Remember Step 4 is the most-important one!  We had just added a MVC 3 application to a "working" (other MVC3 apps already function properly) IIS 6 instance, and forgot to uncheck that and it did not work until that got unchecked.

Answer (score 12):

I believe ASP.NET 4 Extensionless URL feature is not working for virtual directory on iis v6 unless Default Web Site is also set to run ASP.NET v4.0.
For me, setting ASP.NET v4.0 to Default Web Site is not an option since it's breaking existing v2.0 virtual directory webapps.
Adding wildcard application maps on mvc3 virtual directory webapp worked for me.
Here's the list of steps that I did to deploy mvc onto iis6.

1. ASP.NET v4 is already installed on Windows 2003 server
2. Install AspNetMVC3Setup.exe
3. Copy the mvc3 webapp files onto server without mvc3 dlls in the bin folder
4. Create Virtual Directory pointing to the app folder
5. Set the ASP.NET version to 4.0.30319
6. Add Wildcard application map to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll and uncheck the Verify that file exists

Comment: great solution to web sites that has apps using ASP.NET 2.0 together with the MVC app.

Comment: This worked for me without having to set up a separate site for ASP.NET 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**ABOUT WILCARD APPLICATION MAP**: *Be aware that this option causes IIS to intercept every request made against the web server. This includes requests for images, classic ASP pages, and HTML pages. Therefore, enabling a wildcard script map to ASP.NET does have performance implications*.

OTHER SOLUTION: In W2K3 SP2 with IIS6, .NET Framework (2, 3.5, 4).

Goto Registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0

If is necesary create DWORD **EnableExtensionlessUrls with value 0**.

Then from command window execute: resetiis

Create a ASP.NET application from MVC3 Template.

Now in the global.asax setup the routes like theses:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    "Default", // Route name
    //    "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
    //);

    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = "" }
          );

    routes.MapRoute(
      "Root",
      "",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = "" }
    );
}
```

Create AppPool for .NET Framework 4 and setup the web application to use this apppool. You can use the Denis Bauer's ASP.NET Version Switcher or use Aspnet_regiis.exe.

RESULT: the browser shows de About page as the default page.