# MVC3 site / bin deployed / 404 error on image file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC3 website that I am trying to deploy on an existing server with IIS6.  The server has .NET 4 installed, but does not have MVC3 installed.  I've put all of the referenced dll's in my bin folder on the server.

When I set the wildcard map the server throws 404 errors for every document on my site - even static documents (e.g. /public/images/nav.png).  If I get rid of the wildcard map, then I can browse to static images (like nav.png).

Any ideas why 404 errors are occurring for static files that exist when the wildcard map set?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy you solution with MVC3 required DLLs: [How to Deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 App to Web Hosting with "\bin Deployment"](http://kitsula.com/Article/How-to-Deploy-an-ASP-NET-MVC-3-App-to-Web-Hosting-with-bin-Deployment)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately this didn't help.  I was missing some of the dll's referenced in this article and was hoping that was the cause.  But I'm still getting 404 errors on my static files when I set the wildcard map.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Check if solution is running on .NET 4.0 runtimes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345308/mvc-3-deployment-to-iis6

Answer (score 0):

right click on project node , build deployment package ,this works for me .

for more [link] http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx