# How to remove url rewriting in ASP.net C# MVC3 application with IIS6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have developed ASP.net(C#) application with MVC3 but I'm force to run it in IIS6 server which is not support url rewriting.And I don't have default.aspx file too.I don't think I can change IIS server configurations too.following shows my Global.asax.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hello LittleOne. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345308/mvc-3-deployment-to-iis6

Comment: http://www.isapirewrite.com/ you may use this to configure url rerouting on IIS 6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want but maybe this will help: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs

Comment: Yeah it was helpful.I checked that link before.But I'm looking for method within application.Don't we have option to remove rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

@LittleOne : Dude 1st things first . Dont get deflected from the issue, the issue is how to deploy MVC 3 on IIS 6. 
Use [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) to deploy it. It has worked for us . Best of Luck.

Comment: Our server doesn't allow url rewriting because of security concerns.So I'm looking for method within applications.