# Relocating MVC3 application to a subfolder - how to route actions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to deploy a MVC3 app into an IIS6 environment into a sub folder of an existing 2.0 site. The problem I have is that none of the actions are able to hit the controller now I have relocated the application to a subfolder. The controller name is SurveyController and the subdirectory name is Survey.

this is where things go wrong

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AddSurvey")',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(result));
    }
});
```

Now that I've moved into a subfolder what do I need to do to ensure controller actions are routed correctly?

Currently registered routes are

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("", "", new { controller = "Survey", action = "Index" });
```

Edit:

After a few more tests. I am able to browse to a controller that creates an simple hello string. But as soon as I introduce the EF DBContext it throws an error saying

"The IControllerFactory 'UI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'MyTest'. "

```
    public ActionResult MyTest()
    {
        ContentResult cr = new ContentResult();
        cr.Content = "hello";
        return cr;
    }
```

but not

```
    public ActionResult MyTest()
    {
        RolloverModel ctx = new RolloverModel("name=MyModel");
        cr.Content = ctx.Connection.ConnectionString;
        return cr;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used that link originally to deploy the site. The website displays fine - the problem I'm facing is the controller actions were routed as above (last line) so the question is what to change to make it work in a subdirectory

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a jerk, but is there a reason you are trying to deploy to almost a decade old web server?

Comment: by the way, I did a quick search, this might have an answer you need http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: @treehau5 - agreed it sucks using IIS6. Sadly some companies move at a glacial pace... out of my hands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what rellocation you did, but the AJAX example you have shown cannot possibly work because you are using the GET verb with `contentType: 'application/json'` which is not supported by the model binder.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is weird - that's the code that runs from local development (where I'm not using a subdir) In my controller my return action is:-  return Json(allthethings.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. I guess you will have to check your IIS configuration. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. The problem is not related to your code (other than the small bug I pointed out in my answer where you should either use POST or remove the contentType parameter).

Comment: Thanks, not sure what I did but it was basically recreating the app pool, readd mapping to isapi.dll , restart box.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Has your existing website running under 4.0 framework? If not than please switch to 4.0 framework. You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345308/mvc-3-deployment-to-iis6)