# Razor Page Hosted on IIS 6 Fails Every Morning

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a simple page in my intranet which uses Razor/ASP to fetch a single record from a table and display it, plus a few graphic, as a dashboard display. Meaning, no user intervention other then the first time you open IE to the internal URL.

The problem that I am having is that every morning IE displays the "page not found or network error" message. I refresh the page, and it's stuck and doesn't display anything. I try from a different PC, open IE to the internal URL and it's also stuck...

...until I do the following:

- Login to the server hosting the page
- Run inetmgr go to web sites, etc
- Right click on the page that's giving me the problem and select `Browse`

At that moment, I get an error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This type of page is not served. 
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /application/Dashboard.cshtml

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

And I also get this in the Windows Application log:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 5/8/2013 8:05:11 AM 
Event time (UTC): 5/8/2013 12:05:11 PM 
Event ID: 5a7c440506344f5583776e1e1ceb0679 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2103969953/Root-2-130124883110906632 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CCTelecomAdmin\ 
    Machine name: ICSREC1 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 23760 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Path '/application/Dashboard.cshtml' is forbidden.
   at System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:8888/application/Dashboard.cshtml 
    Request path: /application/Dashboard.cshtml 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 2599 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details: 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

The funny thing is that a split second after I get that error on the server, my 2 pages that have been trying to open the URL are "un-stuck" and display the page without any issues for the rest of the day, regardless if I keep the page open all the time (which auto-refreshes every 3 minutes) or if I open new IEs. Next morning, the same story again.

Comment: Is your application pool recycling overnight?

Comment: I didn't do anything to do that. How would I know?

Comment: I have to leave now, when I come back I'll go through this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.01.servingtheweb.aspx

Comment: I unchecked `Recycle Worker Processes`. I'll find out tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

You can't navigate to `/application/Dashboard.cshtml`.  If you have an action `Dashboard` in your `HomeController` then the URL needs to be `Home/Dashboard/` and, assuming that action returns a view without specifying a name, the default return is a view with the same name as the action.

Comment: There has to be something odd about either the application or the way it is set up in IIS.  Would have to see some code to help with the application, and I haven't done the IIS end of MVC3.  But I know you don't navigate to Razor view pages this way.

Comment: Or it could be that you are on IIS 6...I did some looking and see that there are special considerations.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345308/mvc-3-deployment-to-iis6

Comment: It's my first time deploying a site so it's quite likely something's odd about the way it was set up. That link you posted looks like it can teach me a lot. I'll take a look at it. Thanks.