# vs11 mvc4 helloword application does not work

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I want to lear to use mvc4 on vs11 beta professional version

1. I created an ASP.NET MVC 4 WEB APPLICATION
2. I select the Empty  template
3. I create a controller called c1

   ```
   Namespace MvcApplication3
      Public Class c1
         Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

       '
       ' GET: /c1

       Function Index() As ActionResult
           Return View()
       End Function


       Function Hello() As String
           Return "Hello"
       End Function

      End Class
   End Namespace
   ```
4. I run the application and in the browser URL i write "http://localhost:49653/c1/hello"
   but i get this error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /c1/hello
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17379

What am I doing wrong?? Why it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `DefaultControllerFactory` its not enough to inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` but your **controller name have to end with the word "Controller"** (it's a built in convention)

Rename your `c1` to `c1Controller` and it should work:

```
Public Class c1Controller
      Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller
```

Comment: So you still get 404 with the url `/c1/hello` even if you renamed the controller `c1Controller`? Try to clean and rebuild the solution maybe you still run the old code because it should work.

Comment: I created a new project and a new controller  Default1Controller but i have the same problem


Server Error in '/' Application.


 The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Default1Controller

Comment: You just need `Controller` in the controller class name not in the URL. Try it with `/Dafault1` and it should call the `Index` action on the controller `Default1Controller`

Comment: Yes now it works  thanks a lot. I spent 4 hours on this stupid problem

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

1. Ensure that your routes are set up (it looks like you are using
   the default of /Controller/Action) - look here
   http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-vb
2. If you are using an older OS, you may need to add wildcard
   extensionless mapping -
   [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 - wildcard mapping - the incoming request does not match any route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275920/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-wildcard-mapping-the-incoming-request-does-not-match-an)

Comment: Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        routes.MapHttpRoute( _
            name:="DefaultApi", _
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
        )

        routes.MapRoute( _
            name:="Default", _
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub

Comment: Do I have to set up the routes even if i add the address manually in the browser?

Comment: @nemesv had sharper eyes than me - MVC is all about convention :)